# Can't open projects in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

First timer here, very new to SQL and Visual Studio. I'm not able to open any projects/solution in `VS 2015 community edition`. I'm getting a following error:

> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.

These reports were created in VS 2015, so I know they are compatible. Like I said I'm very new at this. I realize my question is quite vague but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What type of project are you trying to open and what version did you install?

Comment: I believe it is a solution ".sln file". I've installed Visual Studio 14.0 2015 Community

Comment: The error is for specific project types in the solution. Please post the exact error. It may be like 'Cannot open the project .vdproj .....' . etc. Depending upon the project type you will need to install the project template.

Comment: The solution file is just a container for projects. Look at what exact project is having errors. Possibly you're missing some plugin or feature needed to open it.

Comment: Since you are saying its the 'reports' related project, you may need to install the reporting tool on your machine too.

Comment: the project type is .rptproj - error says: "The application which this project type is based on was not found". I'm assuming that you are correct in saying I do not have the reporting tool installed.